# How to call a template member function from the <class T> class

Tags: c++, templates

First my code, better to ask the question with code visible.

```
template<class T>
class TemplateClass
{
public:
    TemplateClass()
    {
    };
    ~TemplateClass(){};

    T cc{this};

    void tbcFunction(){};
    void otherFunction(){};
};

class CallerClass
{
public:
    CallerClass(TemplateClass<CallerClass>* tc) : templatePointer(tc){};
    ~CallerClass(){};
    TemplateClass<CallerClass>* templatePointer;

    void myFunction()
    {
        templatePointer->tbcFunction();
    };
};
void setup()
{
    TemplateClass<CallerClass> ct;
    ct.otherFunction();
}
```

I need to call a function from TemplateClass from the code in CallerClass.

One way to achieve that is to provide the "this" from TemplateClass to the CallerClass when instantiating.
That is the solution I have done above with passing it within the constructor.

Are there any negative effects when doing it this way ?

Are there other/better/more elegant solutions for this ?

Comment: You can look towards [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: There's nothing specifically wrong with it, but it _might_ be a bit of a code smell since it makes your ownership model and lifetimes more complicated: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/323130/if-a-has-b-and-b-holds-reference-of-a-is-it-a-flawed-design-need-to-be-fixed